# Can I apply for Spain Schengen visa after my J1 visa expired?

Tags: schengen, spain, visa-expiration, j1-visas, expired

I am from Turkey and I am currently in Usa in Work&Travel program. My J1 visa expired on 22 Sept and my grace period started which ends on 22 Oct. I want to go to Spain to visit some friends before I go back to Turkey
for 10 days on 16 Oct and leave on 27 Oct to go to Turkey. Can I still apply for Schengen Visa? To make it clear, I will not be coming back to Usa, will directly go to Turkey after visiting Spain.